# JQuery position giving absolute coordinates instead of relative

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm working with some JavaScript and noticed some funny stuff happening with one of my Windows. I placed a breakpoint in my code and saw that obj.position() was returning absolute values. I decided to test by running the demo at api.jquery.com/position, and added a few 
 elements to make certain it wasn't just the borders that were acting weird.

The code I modified looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>position demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  p {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<p></p>
 
<script>
var p = $( "p" ).first();
var position = p.position();
$( "p" ).last().text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Which tells me that the position of the "p" element within the div is at 33 left, 129 top.

I'm guessing I'm just not understanding what position() is supposed to return, because I am looking for the position of the p element, relative to the position of the div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position()` returns the position of the element relative to its offset parent. The offset parent is determined to be the closest parent element with `position` set, and if there are none, then it is the `body` element. In your case, the `div` has no position, so `body` is the offset parent. That makes `position()` return what are essentially the absolute coordinates of your `p`.

If you'd like to base things on the `p`'s position inside its parent `div`, you will need to `position` your `div`:

```
div {
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

This makes the `div` the offset parent, and your coordinates will be based on it.

Comment: Thanks so much! Why wasn't that explained in the demo code? I realize I was trying to cut stuff out of my css files and must have gone too far.